# Pipe string to shell command in Haskell

Tags: haskell, process, pipe

How do I feed a string to shell command and 
get the output it produces in Haskell?

For example, given this:

```
> myHaskellProg 
  "blah"

> myHaskellProg | wc
  4
```

I want

```
> myHaskellProg
```

to print `4` by calling `wc` and printing out the result

I was able to call shell commands using `process`'s `callCommand` 
but how do I pipe a string to it and get back the result or stderr?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are looking for `System.Process` and you can use the `shell` function to create a description of a process then use `readCreateProcess` to run the shell command, provide stdin and read stdout.

```
import System.Process
main :: IO ()
main =
  do result <- readCreateProcess (shell "ls") myHaskellString
     putStrLn result

myHaskellString :: String
myHaskellString = "string"
```

Comment: Can you please show me how to print stderr produced from the process?

Comment: Use `readCreateProcessWithExitCode` to capture both the return value and stderr.